# PersonalViews.aspx has javascript embedded in it by previous admin, after upgrade to 2016 now '$ is undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-views

After much trouble, I have finally found a script tag in PersonalViews.aspx that was inserted by previous admin some time ago.  This script tag references some javascript that is breaking when it reaches $.  The error is '$ is undefined'

```
if ($("th").find(".ms-vh-div[name='ID']").parent("th").index() >= 0)
```

I do not know how to resolve this issue.  Please advise?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the jQuery file loading to the browser. Here are the steps

- Open a page in browser (Steps below I am referring to Firefox)
- Open Developer tool (F12)
- Click on network tab and filter JS files by clicking "JS"
- See you can find jQuery library file. It should be loaded inorder work jQuery

There will be conflict sometimes because multiple versions of jQuery files.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("th").find(".ms-vh-div[name='ID']").parent("th").index() >= 0)
```

executes code when a View Column ID exists

and can be done without jQuery:

```
if( GetAncestor(document.querySelector("[name='ID']"),'TH') )
```